# Calculating spatial statistics based on k nearest neighbors' characteristics?

Tags: r, spatial

I am trying to use R to produce some spatial statistics.

My data set consists of a large number of units (100000s). For each unit I have coordinates and a handful of attributes.

Now I want to produce an average statistic of attributes for each individual's k nearest neighbors. What procedure in R should I start with? I would benefit much from some example code.